# Cast to Integer Only If "Lossless"?

Tags: python

I wish to cast a string or a number to an integer only if the casting is "lossless" or, another way to put it, only if the string or number is indeed an integer.

For instance,

- `3.0` (a float that is indeed an integer) -> `3`.
- `'3.000'` (a string that is an integer) -> `3`.
- `3.1` -> exception raised.
- `'4.2'` -> exception raised.

Directly doing `int(x)` will convert `3.1` to `3`.

This is the best I have:

```
def safe_cast_to_int(x):
    int_x = int(x)
    if np.issubdtype(type(x), np.floating):
        assert int_x == x, \
            f"Can't safely cast a non-integer value ({x}) to integer"
    return int_x
```

but I wonder if there is a better or more Pythonic way?

Comment: Should the attempt to convert `(1.03-0.42)*100` raise an error?

Comment: @AnonCoward Haha, for my application, no it shouldn't raise an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to cast something if it's a whole number.
If that's the case, you could first cast it to a float and then check with [`float.is_integer()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) if it's an integer.

Here are the examples with values of the question.

```py
>>> float('3.0').is_integer()
True
>>> float('3.000').is_integer()
True
>>> float('3.1').is_integer()
False
>>> float('4.2').is_integer()
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to `float` and modulus the data with 1 to check if you want to keep it a `float`

```py
val = float(src)
val = int(val) if not val%1 else val
```

Edit: `is_integer()` is just doing the below for you, but with a bunch of conditions and flags attached before it gets to this line.

```c
o = (floor(x) == x) ? Py_True : Py_False;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want things that look like integers, but aren't really integer values, as in `(1.03-0.42)*100`, then you need to test to see how "near" an integer a value is, and accept anything close.  How close you accept as "integer" will depend on your exact use case:

```
import sys
tests = [
    42,
    '1.00',
    3.2,
    (1.03-0.42)*100,
]

for x in tests:
    is_close_to_int = abs(int(float(x))-float(x))<0.00000000001
    print(f"{x}: {float(x).is_integer()} {is_close_to_int}")
```

This outputs:

```
42: True True
1.00: True True
3.2: False False
61.00000000000001: False True
```

Showing that for many cases float's `is_integer` helper will do the right thing, but for some edge cases, a person might expect different results.